# User names that are not linked

Tags: support, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts

I noticed in a few questions, such as [What does a nonstandard proof of Con(PA) look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/what-does-a-nonstandard-proof-of-conpa-look-like) , that the user name that asked the question appears in grey but is not linked. What does that indicate?

**Follow up**: it is a deleted user (as I suspected might be the case). What is the process for an answer to a question like this to be marked as accepted, if the original user is no longer able to do it?

Comment: Questions by a deleted user can never be marked accepted, even moderators are not able to do that. Answers can only be accepted by the user asking the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user who asked this question was QED, who asked to be deleted over a year ago I believe.

Deleted users are not linked, of course.

---

As for the edit, I doubt there is a way to have your answer accepted. However once an answer is upvoted, the question will not be bumped automatically anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It also happens that a question got migrated to any-other.stackexchange.com. The OP might not have an account there. Then his name will also appear in grey.

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15252/1436).